# Why doesn't calling float(hrs) make pay=hrs*2 work later?

Tags: python

It seems that the 'float' function operates differently from what I'm expecting. I wanted to change str variable into float variable. But it seems I cannot change the variable properly

First I used the input function to define "hrs" and then I tried to multiply it by rate. But the BAD code shows me

"can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Hasn't it already changed to float type?

```
hrs=input("enter hours")
rate=2.0
float(hrs)
pay=hrs*rate
print(pay)
```

Comment: `float()` returns a new value it doesn't change the string. You need to save the new value to a variable.

Comment: Use `hrs = float(hrs)` or perhaps simply `hrs=float(input("enter hours"))` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
hrs=float(input("enter hours"))
rate=2.0
pay=hrs*rate
print(pay)
```

or

```
hrs=input("enter hours")
rate=2.0
pay=float(hrs)*rate
print(pay)
```

Comment: That shows how to do it, but it doesn't -- except by inference -- answer the question asked, which is what the OP did wrong.